# Group django queryset by foreign key / related field

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-queryset

Consider two models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    ...
```

The goal is to group answers by questions. I could think of some ways of spanning the model relatioship from the `Question` side - retrieve all the questions which have any answers:

```
Question.objects.annotate(answer_count = Count('answer')) \
                .filter(answer_count__gte=1)
```

Then we can iterate over this QuerySet and use `answer_set` to get particular answers.

The problem here is that if the `Question` table is big enough, this query is **very slow**. It's even more ugly in a situation when most of the questions don't have any answers and you end up annotating a huge table with zeros.

It would be great to go from the other side of the relationship and somehow group `Answer` instances by `question__id` field. The way I'm handling it now is:

```
answered_questions = [row['question'] for row in 
    Answer.objects.values('question').distinct('question')]
for question in answered_questions:
    answers = Answer.objects.filter(question__id=question)
```

This is obviously faster but also clumsy. Grouping objects by foreign key should be a pretty common task. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple query you can make would be:

```
qs = Question.objects.annotate(answer_count = Count('answers')) \
            .filter(answer_count__gte=1).prefetch_related('answers')
# get answer list related to first question
print qs[0].answers.all()
```

assuming you've added `related_name` attribute:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answers')
```

I can't imagine a use case of getting all the questions from the database, you typically paginate the data or something, so the slow queries should not be an issue.

Comment: In a situation where most of the questions have no answers we fetch most of the Question objects just to see their `answer_set` is empty, right? What kind of pagination would fix that problem?

Comment: So you don't want to fetch the questions at all, if they have zero answers? Regarding pagination, it depends on how do render data, so we need more details.

Comment: Yes, I want to only fetch questions that have some answers, sorry if it's not clear from the question. My Django app is only making queries against a DB and serializing data to feed it to client-side JavaScript for rendering.

Comment: @martinthenext I've updated my answer, which basically adds your filtering to avoid empty answers. Regarding pagination, you can simply fetch resource with ajax by adding `?page=10` or so. There're a lot of examples how to paginate data using ajax, so please try to look around.